# Eclipse Plug-in Development: DefaultInformationControl Does'nt work as expected

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hover, eclipse-jdt

I am writing eclipse plugin that using the texthover and override it for my own text.
I need to add an action to the hover window so I used the following function:

```java
public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator()
```

This is my code:

```java
@Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {

    return new IInformationControlCreator() {
        public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
            Shell s=new Shell(parent,SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
            ToolBarManager tbm = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
            NoFocusDic dic = new NoFocusDic(parent, tbm);
            dic.setBackgroundColor(new Color(null,123,234,12));
            ButtonAction ba=new ButtonAction();
            tbm.add(ba);
            tbm.update(true);
            dic.setSize(300,100);
            dic.setLocation(new Point(500,500));
        //  dic.setInformation("abc");
            dic.setVisible(true);
            return dic;

        }
    };
}
```

When I run this code with the setInformation line I get this window:

[image: the window I get with the setInformation line]

And when I run it without the setInformation line I get this window:

[image: the window I get without the setInformation line]

So The window I want to always get is the second one, but *with* text inside.
I read in eclipse site that the setVisible won't work if I try to catch the focus, but I don't think that setInformation is catching focus.

Any Ideas what to do?

```java
package TextHoverPackage;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultInformationControl;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IInformationControl;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IInformationControlCreator;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IInformationControlExtension2;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class NoFocusDic extends DefaultInformationControl implements IInformationControlExtension2 {

    public NoFocusDic(Shell parent, ToolBarManager toolBarManager) {
        super(parent, toolBarManager);
    }

    public NoFocusDic(Shell parent, ToolBarManager toolBarManager, IInformationPresenter a){
        super(parent, toolBarManager,a);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInput(Object arg0) {
        super.setInformation(arg0.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `NoFocusDic`?

Comment: @greg-449 just a class that extends from DefaultInformationControl  and implements IInformationControlExtension2 for make the window to be what it is in pictue number 2. P.S just add this class code to the quastion

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultInformationControl.setInformation` adjusts the size of the window to fix the text that you give it. However it only does this if an `IInformationPresenter` has been defined.

So one option is to specify `null` for the `IInformationPresenter` in your constructor:

```java
public NoFocusDic(Shell parent, ToolBarManager toolBarManager) {
    super(parent, toolBarManager, null);
}
```

Comment: This is not what you said you did. I am saying call setInformation but with a null information presenter. The Constructor you used uses HTMLInformationPresenter.

Comment: I edit my Constructor and replace my line with your line and still no change. My real problem is that the first picture return to normal hover looking after moving the mouse on it (yellow color and without my action).  P.S. Do you know how can I find the source code of the DefaultInformationControl?

Comment: To get the Eclipse Source install 'Eclipse Platform SDK' from the updates site for your release (`http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5` for Eclipse Mars). Then in the Preferences on the 'Plug-in Development' tab select 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search'. Once you have done this you can open all the Eclipse source in the same way as any other Java file. Note if you are using a target platform you need to install in the target platform rather than the running Eclipse.